# issue while constructing the URL dynamically

Tags: java, html, jsp

Could not able to open URL with the below  link.

```
Test<a href='#'onClick=window.open('\\160.53.112.171\myTest\cons\4.1\displayData.htm','_self') >
```

But when i copy and paste "`\\160.53.112.171\myTest\cons\4.1\displayData.htm`" in the browser it open's a page.How can i dynamically construct a href link to open the above URL.
Issue is its appending some special characters in the URL when i click on the link through  and page could not be opened.Please suggest.

--EDIT--

Below is the generated URL when i click the dynamically created URL:

```
file:///C:/160.53.112.171myTestcons%04.1displayData.htm
```

This Webpage is not Found message is displayed on the browser.

Comment: can you please paste the url that is generated when you click this hyper link?

Comment: @zerocool - Generated URL : file:///C:/160.53.112.171myTestcons%04.1displayData.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try `//160.53.112.171/myTest/cons/displayData.htm`. Use '/' instead of  '\'.

Comment: @TartanLlama - i tried using '/' instead of '\' but didn't worked.

Comment: @scrit, not my answer, I just edited the formatting.

Comment: @akSahli - i tried using '/' instead of '\' but didn't worked.

Comment: @TartanLlama, `http://160.53.112.171/myTest/cons/4.1/displayData.htm` should work.

Comment: @akSahli - A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out" error is displaying. But when i appended file://160.53.112.171/myTest/cons/4.1/displayData.htm it was working fine in IE but not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In Java , Any Location based retrieval  can be done using the Forward Slash.

In real life, it will be Back Slash.

> Replace "\" with "//"
>
> Replace "\" with "/"

In your case, in you have any special symbols in the URL. You may need to use the URLEncoder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: I tried but its not working. In chrome its throwing below error on console:Not allowed to load local resource:  file:///C:/160.53.112.171myTestcons%04.1displayData.htm  , works fine in IE. URL i'am trying to access is  file:\\160.53.112.171\myTest\cons\4.1\displayData.htm which works in IE.